# What is $p_0$ in the rocket thrust equation $F = \dot m * V_e + (p_e - p_0) * A_e $ and how do I calculate it?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rocket-science

I am doing a computer science project on a rocket simulation and i am using the thrust equation

$$F = \dot m * V_e + (p_e - p_0) * A_e $$

however I cant find any articles that clearly explain what the pressure variables are within this equation are.

If someone could explain what they are and how to calculate them within different environments(e.g earth, mars or different booster sizes) that would be great.

Comment: https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/rocket/rktpow.html

Answer (score 0):

$p_0$ is the atmospheric pressure.  It's 1 atm when launching from sea level, and very close to 0 once one is in space.